# Tests start to run before angular binding the value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using protractor for angular E2E test, sometimes the tests start to run before angular binding the value.

[image]

I tried to use browser.sleep before and after browser.get() but still not working, also browser.waitForAngular() after navigate to the URL.

```
it("Send URL to the browser",function(){
    browser.get(params.login.url);
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

Comment: Is adding `browser.waitForAngular()` after navigating to the page helping?

Comment: Hi alecxe, No I added browser.waitForAngular() and still not working

Comment: @user1684140 Did you also try to use the promise that `waitForAngular()` function returns and then send values to the input fields? Here's how - `browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){//Your commands to send text to the username and password fields});`. Or try increasing your implicit wait timeout interval so that protractor can wait till that time.

Comment: @GirishSortur Thank you, working great :).

Comment: @user1684140 updated it as answer. Glad that it helped you. If you feel that its the correct answer kindly mark it as answer so that others can get help out of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the promise that `waitForAngular()` function returns and then send values to the input fields. That way protractor knows to wait for angular to settle and then execute the commands that you want on the angular objects. Here's how -

```
browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){
    //Your commands to send text to the username and password fields
});
```

Hope it helps.